# Get a thumbnail from a Bitmap located at a web address

Tags: android, xamarin, thumbnails, android-bitmap, webaddress

In Xamarin, is it possible to get a thumbnail of a `Bitmap` that is hosted at a web address?

I have this code:

```
public static int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    var height = (float)options.OutHeight;
    var width = (float)options.OutWidth;
    var inSampleSize = 1D;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {
        inSampleSize = width > height
                            ? height/reqHeight
                            : width/reqWidth;
    }

    return (int) inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options {
        InJustDecodeBounds = true,
    };
    using (var dispose = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options)) {
    }

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Can this code be modified to get a thumbnail of a `Bitmap` that is stored at a web address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can download the whole image and then scale it according to your needs and show to the user its the only option

Comment: So it is not possible then?

Comment: you either have to do as I said above or have a dedicated scaled image in your server. Downloading a thumbnail(30*50 lets say) from a url pointing to (150*150 ) is not possible

Comment: OK, thank you. I was just wondering if it was possible from a byte array perspective.